# Configmap indentation does not render properly

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am currently building a generic chart for a Kubernetes Cronjob. I have the following template function to include a configMap:

```
{{- define "cronjob.volume.configMap" -}}
        {{- $name := index . 0 -}}
        {{- $configMapName := index . 1 -}}

        name: {{ $name }}
        configMap:
            name: {{ $configMapName }}
{{- end -}}
```

I am including this template in a chart like this:

```
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
        {{- if .Values.configs }}
          volumes:
          - {{ include "cronjob.volume.configMap" (list "config" "cronjob-config") }}
        {{- end }}
```

My values.yaml looks like this:

```
configs:
  test-config: |-
    test-config-string
```

When running `helm template`, I am expecting the result to be the following:

```
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
          - name: config
            configMap:
                name: cronjob-config
```

However, the generated result is this:

```
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
          - name: config
        configMap:
            name: cronjob-config
```

The first line of my template has proper indentation, the 2nd and 3rd line however end up at the same indentation level as `volumes`, right under `spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec`. I have tried using `include` instead of `template` in conjunction with `indent` but without success unfortunately. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could be due to editor you are using. Try to cat the file in terminal and see if indentation is correct

Comment: Catting the configMap template file in terminal does show correct indentation, this is the file you meant right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nindent](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) function and remove indentation from helper function:

**_helpers.tpl**

```yaml
{{ define "cronjob.volume.configMap" }}
{{- $name := index . 0 -}}
{{- $configMapName := index . 1 -}}
- name: {{ $name }}
  configMap:
    name: {{ $configMapName }}
{{- end -}}
```

**cronjob.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
        {{- if .Values.configs }}
          volumes:
          {{- include "cronjob.volume.configMap" (list "config" "cronjob-config") | nindent 10 }}
        {{- end }}
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

```sh
➜ helm template .
---
# Source: achart/templates/cronjob.yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
          - name: config
            configMap:
              name: cronjob-config
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Thanks! Using the `nindent` function like you suggested does indeed work for me. I also noticed you put the `-` before the `name` key inside the template instead of in the file which includes the template. Is this generally recommended in these scenarios?

Comment: In my opinion it makes template more readable and consistent, and as 'nindent' adds a new line at the beginning of the string, I'm not sure the template would successfully render without moving '-' to function

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, sounds sensible. I tried it the other way around and the template does render successfully, however a newline is inserted between `-` and `name: {{ $name }}` in this case. So that indeed is not practical.